# Show that $f(x,y)=2x-y$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f(x,y)=2x-y$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Use the definition.
How can I do this using just the definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: Can you use the definition of continuity? Can you show that in that case, given an $\epsilon>0$, the same $\delta$ works everywhere? That is what uniform continuity is, so you're done!

Comment: The title should be: "Show that f(x,y) = 2x - y is uniformly continuous"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x,y,a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. We want
$$\left|f(x,y)-f(a,b)\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|2x-y-2a+b\right|<\epsilon$$
Because 
$$\left|2x-y-2a+b\right|\le 2\left|x-a\right|+\left|y-b\right|$$
it suffices
$$2\left|x-a\right|+\left|y-b\right|<\epsilon$$
when
$$\left|(x-a,y-b)\right|<\delta\implies\left|x-a\right|<\delta\text{ and }\left|y-b\right|<\delta$$
Choosing $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3}>0$ will do the trick. Because $\delta$ doesn't depend on $x,y,a,b$, the continuity is uniform